# How can I get the count of the current iteration with pandas iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate over a `DataFrame`, but the `index`, I get when looking through `iterrows()` is the index in the DataFrame. Instead, I want it to be `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`...

```
        for ind, row in last_10.iterrows():
            print('ind', ind)
```

This returns:

```
2345
2346
2347
...
```

I want it to be:

```
0
1
2
...
```

Comment: `for ind, row in last_10.reset_index(drop=True).iterrows()` but please don't use `iterrows`.

Comment: I don't want to modify `last_10`

Comment: What would you suggest instead of `iterrows`?

Comment: It is a temporary modification.... It doesn't stick

Comment: Something that is vectorised. Not going to elaborate unless you explain what you are doing here

Comment: Or you can do something I wouldn't recommend such as using enumerate with iterrows.  `for ind, row in enumerate(df_last_5.iterrows()):` to access row data, you'd do `row[1]`

Comment: Okay - can you create an answer and I can accept

Comment: @coldspeed has the best answer.  I think.

Comment: Also you could look at `pd.factorize(last_10.index)[0]` may be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `enumerate`

```
for ind, row in enumerate(last_10.iterrows()):
    print('ind', ind)
    print('data',row[1]['columns'])
```

---

`range` create

```
for ind in range(len(last_10)):
    print('ind', ind)
    print('data',df.iloc[ind]['columns'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    from itertools import tee 


    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], columns = ['value'])

    def pair_iterate(iter):
        first, second = tee(iter)
        next(second, None)
        return zip(first, second)

    for (i1, row1), (i2, row2) in pair_iterate(df.iterrows()):
        print(i1, i2, row1["value"], row2["value"])
```